# Why nested types' scope does not include derived classes?

Tags: delphi, types, nested

I wonder why the scope of nested types does not include derived classes in Delphi; it could make code more clean:

```
type
  TBaseTest = class
  public type
    PVector = ^TVector;
    TVector = record
      A, B, R: Integer;
    end;
  public
    procedure Execute(var Vector: TVector); virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TTestA = class(TBaseTest)
  public
// E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TVector'
    procedure Execute(var Vector: TVector); override;
// workaround:
//  procedure Execute(var Vector: TBaseTest.TVector); override;
  end;
```

Comment: I wouldn't call your "workaround" a workaround. How would you distinguish between TVector's that are nested types of two different classes? Though, admittedly, in derived classes it could default to the base type's TVector...

Comment: I'd guess that the designers wanted to avoid ambiguity. Perhaps they learnt from years of working with the ghastly `with` statement.

Comment: possible solution is introducing 'sealed' nested types, i.e. the types that can't be redeclared in derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, when you write TVertor in TBaseTest, the compiler looks for it first in this class, then in this unit, then in modules in Uses section. That's why you can write simple TVector, meaning TBaseTest.TVector.

When you write a class TTestA, derived from TBaseTest, and use TVector there, it looks first in TTestA (there's no TVector), then in this module (there's no TVector too), then in Uses. If you want to use inner class of TBaseTest, you should write directly TBaseTest.TVector, because TVector is defined in TBaseTest, not in TTestA.

Comment: The last sentence is rather pointless. It repeats what appears in the question.

Comment: I meant that inner classes are not inheritable, like TBaseTest.TVector and TTestA.TVector are different.

Comment: That is stated in the question. Question is asking why the design is why it is.